# Softether VPN server - not reachable from outside

Tags: vpn, port-forwarding, softether

I am pretty new to vpn, but i have set up anything written down in the softether documentation.

So, i am able to connect locally from every machine in my net to the vpn server, but from outside, i only got a timeout.

This implicite, that it must be my router which blocks the needed ports.
So i did some portforwading to the server.... 
It still doesnt work.

I have a fritzbox 6320.

I can ping the server from outside. (With the softether ddns).

I really need some help here. If you need configuration files, i can provide them.

Comment: It looks like the FRITZ!Box is responding to the ping from the internet. How did you configure port forwarding on the FRITZ!Box? Have you tried the "expose host" option (this will forward all internet traffic to your softether server, with the exception of other explicitly forwarded ports, so use this option with caution). The manual doesn't have a lot of details on specifically how to set up port forwarding, unfortunately.

Comment: i tried every combination and even only the exposed host entry in the fb. Thats really weird. I dont know where to look first. The assistant in softether is pretty simple. So is my configuration but i think this is just enough to make it work. Can i see somehow if the fritzbox is really blocking the connection? If i wireshark the traffic, how can i see what is supposed to route to my machine? =)

Comment: I'd first try to set up something a bit more simple: just forward port 22 to a machine running an SSH server or forward port 80 to a machine running a web server and see if it connects successfully, to rule out an issue with softether. I'm also wondering if your ISP has blocks on incoming traffic; in which case, the packets won't even make it to the FRITZ!Box.

Comment: Okay, my webserver isn't reachable too. I did some research on my ISP and it occurs that I am on ds-lite which means outside its ipv4 and ipv6 on my side. Now I have to check how to manage that...

Comment: That sounds like you should have an IPv6 address then. Can you access your website from the IPv6 address?

Comment: Austinian, a bit late but i had to configure a portmapping. (i have use feste-ip.net).